# Generating a compile-time constant integer from a literal string

Tags: c++, embedded, portability, realview

I have a problem with non-portable code that works as intended on ARM RealView compiler, but VC++, GCC refuse to compile it and QAC++(a static analysis tool) issues a warning.

### The problem

I have a system that needs to parse mnemonic identifiers in messages.  The mnemonics are all three character 8-bit ASCII strings.  To simplify and optimise parsing rather than performing string compare against the mnemonic string I pack the string into an 32-bit integer and perform an integer comparison.

Further in order to be able to use a switch/case rather than if-elseif chain, I have a macro that takes a literal string and generates the associated integer, which in ARM RealView is a compile time constant, but not in GCC x86/Linux or VC++/Windows:

```
// Note:  Do not change C cast to static_cast because compiler complains when used in switch/case
#define CONST_MNEMONIC( mn ) ((uint32_t)(((#mn)[2]<<16)|((#mn)[1]<<8)|((#mn)[0])))
```

This is then used on the ARM target code as follows:

```
switch( packed_mnemonic )
{
    case CONST_MNEMONIC(RST) :
        ...
        break ;

    case CONST_MNEMONIC(SSD) :
        ...
        break ;

    case CONST_MNEMONIC(DEL) :
        ...
        break ;

    default:
        ...
        break ;
}
```

The case label of course must be a compile-time constant, but apparently this is not the case for all compilers.  The code is non-portable, and either I guess undefined or implementation defined behaviour, or just plain wrong!

### The questions

The obvious portable solutions have disadvantages of efficiency and maintainability, so I have two questions:

1. Why is this code not portable - what makes the macro not compile-time constant in some compilers?
2. Is there a portable solution to generating the desired compile time constant from the mnemonic string?

Comment: One problem you have is that when you use `#mn` in the macro, you are creating the string literal `"mn"`. To use the actual string literal passed to the macro drop the stringify operation.

Comment: Do you have 3 arrays `char RST[],SSD[],DEL[]` declared somewhere? A significant piece of your code is missing, making it hard to ananlyze the problem at hand.

Comment: Looks like you found platform specificity in the ARM compiler with its willingness to compile this.  The reason this isnt an ICE is becausse of the shift, I believe.  In any case, I have done this before.  When I get to work I'll try to find the code..

Comment: Are you using C++11 or some other version?

Comment: which version are your compiler ?

Comment: I think its the indexing into the string that's not portably compile time. IIRC doing bitwise shifts at compile time has pretty much always been standard.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: My apologies, the macros are not used that way - the "" are omitted from the parameter.  I have edited the question.

Comment: @barakmanos: Yes I have elided the code, but everything you need is there (although I have since corrected the macro usage example).  There is no RST symbol etc., the preprocessor converts the macro parameters to string literals in `#mn`.

Comment: @Jarod42:  For what it is worth currently *RealView ARM Compiler toolchain v5.02*, but the code been used for a while over several versions, and has also worked on Microchip's C31 (dsPIC/PIC24) C compiler.

Comment: @JohnDibling: a C++2003 solution would be preferable to conform to our coding standard - few embedded target compilers other than GCC support C++x11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With C++11 you could use a [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) function:

```
constexpr int CONST_MNEMONIC(const char* s)
{
    return (static_cast<int>(s[2]) << 16) +
           (static_cast<int>(s[1]) <<  8) +
            static_cast<int>(s[0]);
}
```

Comment: So much easier in C++11 than it was in C++03.  I struggled for days to build something that took you like 30 seconds.  Ok, yeah.  Maybe I'm a little jealous.

Comment: [Documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0205j/Bgbdhgjd.html) indicates C++ 2003.  However, this solution can be used on VC++ and GCC which we use for simulation and unit testing with a target specific conditional definition.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It compiles fine here with gcc 4.8 and clang 3.4...

In C++11, you may use:

```
constexpr uint32_t CONST_MNEMONIC(const char (&s)[4])
{
    return (uint32_t(s[2]) << 16) | (uint32_t(s[1]) << 8) | uint32_t(s[0]);
}
```